# How to install a virtual console font on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, console, fonts

I want to change my virtual console font to Inconsolata. I installed it with `pacman -S ttf-inconsolata`, but when I do `ls /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/` I still don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console doesn't use TTF fonts, like Inconsolata.

You can use an application like [Fbterm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fbterm) that can draw text with freetype2 to allow you to use TTF/OTF type fonts.